# FFMPEG Audio and Video Streams merging and restreaming

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I have multiple streaming sources that need to combined and re-streamed as a single source.

My sources are:

- A local low rate RTP audio stream
- A camera

I need to redistribute the combined stream (via UDP multicast) across the local network.

The problem I am seeing is that periodically ffmpeg appears to lock up and stop processing the combination after an indeterminate amount of time (sometimes as little as 15 min sometimes almost an hour). However if I redirect the streams independently (audio or video only) there appears to be no problem and the run indefinitely.

**Command**

```
ffmpeg -f rtp -i rtp://127.0.0.1:6666 -f video4linux2 -standard NTSC -s 704x480 -i /dev/video1 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -preset ultrafast -r 3 -g 3 -keyint_min 6 -x264opts "keyint=6:min-keyint=6:no-scenecut" -b:v 200k -ac 1 -b:a 64k -f mpegts udp://225.1.1.15:30000
```

**Output**

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.1-   http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 18 2014 09:06:26 with gcc 4.8 (Debian 4.8.3-19)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-shared --disable-    debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-    libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --    enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --    enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --    disable-ffserver --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --cc=gcc-4.8
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rtp @ 0xb61abe0] Guessing on RTP content - if not received properly you need an SDP file describing it
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, rtp, from 'rtp://127.0.0.1:6666':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1424887596.039777, bitrate: 162039 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559`enter code here`), yuyv422, 704x480, 162039 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0xb61f900] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0xb61f900] profile High 4:2:2, level 2.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://225.1.1.15:30000':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv422p, 704x480, q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 3 fps, 90k tbn, 3 tbc
    Metadata:
       encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
       encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 ac3
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_mulaw (native) -> ac3 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=12.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.33 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the only way I was able to get the streams to run for an extended period was to split them into two independent streams.